# WebClient FileDownload cancels after some time by downloading from cdn

Tags: c#, file, download, webclient, cdn

I am using a simple System.Net.WebClient to download a large file (about 1,5 GB) from a rented Content Delivery Network (so its not a server that i can set up by myself). I don't expericened the problem myself yet but about 30% of my customers complain about restarting downloads. 
Normally their downloads stop at the same percentage +- one or two percent. For each customer it cancels/restarts the download at a different percentage.

I can't really explain that I just had the idea that the hosting servers sends a timeout but since it's a professional CDN I can't imagine that its' their fault..

Do you have any ideas what else could cause this problem?

The programming code is nothing special: I am just creating a WebClient and downloading the file with "DownloadFileAsync(..)"

For those who want to check the code anyways:

```
        public async Task<FileInfo> downloadServerGameFiles()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string file = string.Format("{0}\\gamefiles{1}.tmp", StorageFolder.FullName, getServerVersion().Result);
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }

            ManualResetEvent downloadFinished = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            int previousPercentage = -1;
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!e.ProgressPercentage.Equals(previousPercentage))
                {
                    previousPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
                    OnStateChanged(this, String.Format("Downloading game files ({0} %) ..", e.ProgressPercentage));
                    BridgeManager.logNow(String.Format("Downloading game files ({0} %) ..", e.ProgressPercentage));
                }
            };
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (previousPercentage == 100)
                {
                    BridgeManager.logNow("Game files downloaded!");
                    downloadFinished.Set();
                }
                else
                {
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(downloadGameAddr, file);
                }
            };


             client.DownloadFileAsync(downloadGameAddr, file);

            downloadFinished.WaitOne();

            return new FileInfo(file);
        });

        return await task;
    }
```

Comment: and where is the code that does the things you described?

Comment: I've left my crystal ball in my other pants. How can anyone realistically answer why random clients get random disconnections? Their internet cut out. Their internet is slow. There was a problem on the internet. The CDN had an issue (it happens). The download was blocked. Ask your CDN provider if they have an idea what's wrong.

Comment: I added the code so you can check if you see any problems..